# Execute several instances of script same time

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a crontable that executes a script with different args

```
0,5,10 * * * * /path/to/logScript "script2"
0,5,10 * * * * /path/to/logScript "script1" 
0,5,10 * * * * /path/to/logScript "script3"
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash     
    script=$1

    $script args >/path/tmp/log.out 2>/path/tmp/log.err
    if [ ! -s  /path/tmp/log.err ]; then
       echo -n "$(date) success: " >> /path/logfile
       cat /path/tmp/log.out >> /path/logfile
    else
       echo -n "$(date) errors: " >> /path/logfile
       cat /path/tmp/log.err >> /path/logfile
    fi
```

The issue that I think i'm having is with the execution of the script in the same time. The script doen't get the right value of return (to know wheter it's stderr or stdout). If i execute the crontable lines one after one in a terminal it works fine but when it's executed automatically the data i get is incorrect.

I tried to solve this by making this changement to crontable but i still have the same issue.

```
0,5,10 * * * * /path/to/logScript "script2"&
0,5,10 * * * * /path/to/logScript "script1"& 
0,5,10 * * * * /path/to/logScript "script3"&
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @malyy see my edit

Comment: Your scripts write their output at the same time to the same files (`/path/tmp/log.out`, `/path/tmp/log.err` and `/path/logfile`).

Comment: when you run the script add a lock file, then other scripts need to check the lock file exist or not, if the lock file not exist execute the second script. if you try to use the same resource with different execution times, it gives you unpredictable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all commands are running at same time, think you could combine the command in a unique one, using & at end of commands to push them to background mode, like this:

```
0,5,10 * * * * /bin/bash -c '/path/to/logScript "script2" &  /path/to/logScript "script1" & /path/to/logScript "script3" & '
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it as a background process (add "&" at the end of the process line so you can "spawn" them)

you can also wrap it into a loop with i being number of processes and run it within the same file.

```
func () {
 #do this
 #do that
 #hit him with a bat
}
```

then in sh
     #!/bin/bash

```
 for i in $(seq 0 5);

 do

 function() & 

 echo "child pid: " $! 

 done
```